# Looping Animations Through A Script? Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, 2d

This may not be like the title says it is.

But I'm basically trying to play an animation through a script. All is going well, there is a error

> ArgumentException: Legacy clips cannot be used in Playables.

Could you help me with that too? and it is playing but I have set the loop to true and for some reason, it will not loop. Is there a way to loop an animation through a script?

This is my code so far:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float moveSpeed = 1f;
    public Animation idleAnim;


    public void Start () {
        idleAnim.Play();
    }
    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if( Input.GetKey("a")) {
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.left * moveSpeed);
        }

        if ( Input.GetKey("d")) {
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.right * moveSpeed);
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help!

(I'm creating a idle animation if you didn't notice)

Comment: Just to be sure, the brackets are not inside the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mark your animation to be looped, select animation asset and set the flag to true in inspector. Also, you should make use of Animtor component, add the idle animation to it, add another empty state, make some boolean parameter to trigger transition between idle animation and empty animation state, call it "isIdle" for example, (you will probably add more animation states in the future, like moving animation for example), in your code you can change "isIdle" parameter of the Animator, when moving, set it to false, when stop moving set it to true. Overall, I would strongly suggest you to watch some sort of tutorial about animation Final State Machine in Unity so you can have better understanding of what all this.